# pybind11 Redirect python sys.stdout to c++ from print()

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a c++ program with a pybind11 embedded python interpreter, executing the following python file, it prints directly to `std::cout`

```
# test.py
print("text")
```

The c++ program executing the file:

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

int main() {
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    py::eval_file("test.py");
}
```

Other solutions I found required modifying the python file - how can I redirect python sys.stdout to c++ as a std::string **without** modifying the python code using only the print() statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This github issue describes a way:
https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1622

Copying the code from that issue verbatim. The following bit was recommended to make it work:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py = pybind11;
```

From the issue:

```cpp
class PyStdErrOutStreamRedirect {
    py::object _stdout;
    py::object _stderr;
    py::object _stdout_buffer;
    py::object _stderr_buffer;
public:
    PyStdErrOutStreamRedirect() {
        auto sysm = py::module::import("sys");
        _stdout = sysm.attr("stdout");
        _stderr = sysm.attr("stderr");
        auto stringio = py::module::import("io").attr("StringIO");
        _stdout_buffer = stringio();  // Other filelike object can be used here as well, such as objects created by pybind11
        _stderr_buffer = stringio();
        sysm.attr("stdout") = _stdout_buffer;
        sysm.attr("stderr") = _stderr_buffer;
    }
    std::string stdoutString() {
        _stdout_buffer.attr("seek")(0);
        return py::str(_stdout_buffer.attr("read")());
    }
    std::string stderrString() {
        _stderr_buffer.attr("seek")(0);
        return py::str(_stderr_buffer.attr("read")());
    }
    ~PyStdErrOutStreamRedirect() {
        auto sysm = py::module::import("sys");
        sysm.attr("stdout") = _stdout;
        sysm.attr("stderr") = _stderr;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
{
    PyStdErrOutStreamRedirect pyOutputRedirect{};
    py::print("hello world");
    // Other noisy python functions can be put here
    assert(pyOutputRedirect.stdoutString() == "hello world\n")
}
// sys.stdout is back to its original state
```

Answer (score 1):

What does 'capture' mean in this context? Ultimately, whether python or C++, writing goes through the OS. If the intend is simply to silence the output, write it to a file, send it to another process, etc., etc. you can intercept all output at that level.

Here is an example that squashes all stdout output for the duration of the python script, then restores after which stdout behaves as before (for python and otherwise):

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <unistd.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

int main() {

    auto fdo = fileno(stdout);
    auto savefd = dup(fdo);
    auto f = fopen("/dev/null", "w");
    dup2(fileno(f), fdo);

    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    py::eval_file("test.py");

    fflush(stdout);
    dup2(savefd, fdo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My implementation is as follows

The principle is to implement a module to replace `sys.stdout`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(my_sys, m) {
    struct my_stdout {
        my_stdout() = default;
        my_stdout(const my_stdout &) = default;
        my_stdout(my_stdout &&) = default;
    };

    py::class_<my_stdout> my_stdout(m, "my_stdout");
    my_stdout.def_static("write", [](py::object buffer) {
        std::cout << buffer.cast<std::string>();
    });
    my_stdout.def_static("flush", []() {
        std::cout << std::flush;
    });

    m.def("hook_stdout", []() {
        auto py_sys = py::module::import("sys");
        auto my_sys = py::module::import("my_sys");
        py_sys.attr("stdout") = my_sys.attr("my_stdout");
    });
}

auto main(int argc, char **argv) -> int {
    py::scoped_interpreter python;

#if 0
    py_stdout.attr("write") = py::cpp_function([](py::object info) {
        std::cout << "info" << std::endl;
    });
#else
    py::module::import("my_sys").attr("hook_stdout")();
#endif

    py::print("Hello, World!\n")

    return 0;
}
```